# Salesforce Flow - Loop - Database Access potential limits issue

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-flow

I'm new to flow, and finally managed to get a flow working, but the Flow Builder tips is advising the following;

*Remove Database Access from Loops
A loop contains a/an Get Records element. To avoid reaching per-transaction flow limits, move the "Topic Keyword Ids" element outside the loop, and have it act on a collection.*

*Remove Database Access from Loops
A loop contains a/an Create Records element. To avoid reaching per-transaction flow limits, move the "Assign Topic to a record" element outside the loop, and have it act on a collection.*

It took me days to get to this point, so don't want to mess it up again, any advice how to restructure the flow would be appreciated.

Salesforce Flow - Parse multi-select values, find and assign Topics:
[image]

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to imagine what each of those flow items is doing without drilling into it.

The issue is obvious though. You are querying (get records) and writing (creating new) to the database in a loop. You should always avoid that.

The second is easier to fix than the first.

You hardly ever have to create in a loop. Just create a new record collection variable of the correct type. In each iteration, use a variable *assignment* item to add the record you wish to create to the collection. Then, after the loop exits, you can use a `create records` item to write the collection to the database.

The first issue is more difficult to solve since you can't use a collection variable as a filter condition in flow. See [here](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DlzeAAC). 1 problem is certainly better than 2...

You can convert this into an apex trigger if you start to bump up into limits...